# Simulador de lanzamiento de dado en Python

Tags: python, funciones, revisión-de-código

Estoy tratando de crear una función que cada vez que sea llamada, genere una lista de 100 lanzamientos aleatorios de un dado utilizando la librería random.

```
import random

def dice():
    dado = []
    for i in range(100):
        dado.append(random.choice(range(1,7)))
        return dado

dice()
```

Cuando corro la función, sólo me regresa un valor. Por otra parte, cuando hago esto:

```
def dice():
    dado = []
    for i in range(100):
        dado.append(random.choice(range(1,7)))
        print(dado)
```

Me regresa 100 listas. La primera contiene un número, la siguiente dos, y así hasta imprimir la lista 100 con 100 números. Como señalé, lo que quiero es que se imprima una sola lista de 100 números aleatorios.

Quiero señalar que me interesa también que la lista resultante pueda ser graficada a través de un histograma, por ejemplo.

Cualquier ayuda u orientación es muy apreciada. ¡Gracias!

Comment: cuando utilizas `return dado`, `dice()` sale devolviendo ese valor. Por tanto, ya no sigue recorriendo el bucle.

Comment: Exacto el return está dentro del bucle for, por lo que te muestra 1 valor y termina.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error está en la función "dice()", el return debería tener un tabulado menos, para que se devuelva cuando termine el bucle.

```
def dice():
  dado = []
  for i in range(100):
      dado.append(random.choice(range(1,7)))
  return dado
```

Te dejo un ejemplo en este enlace [click](http://codepad.org/VnMkq2Xg)

Comment: Gracias. Sigo olvidando ese pequeño detalle de las sangrías (el problema de ser un usuario habitual de R). ¡Saludos!

Answer (score 1):

Los lanzamientos de dados, puedes tomarlo como una sucesión de eventos aleatorios, sin complicar el problema añadiendo probabilidad condicionada, podrías usar la la librería de python `random`:

```
import random
# siendo N el numero de elementos de tu lista(numero de tiradas)
def dado(n):
    result=[]
    for i in xrange(0,n):
        result.append(random.randint(1, 6))
    return result

dado(10)
Out[0]:[2, 5, 1, 3, 4, 4, 5, 1, 1, 4]
```